# Add Send-As email (request) with domain name outside of current account

Tags: google-admin-sdk, google-email-settings-api, google-email-migration

Due to a merge, we have domain A under one Google Apps acccount, domain B under another one. I can create accounts for all the users in domain B to domain A to start a migration afterward. Adding aliasses with domains under account A is no problem.

However, sending email as the account under domain B (which users can request manually with their account, the account in domain B will then be mailed with the question whether they want to allow it) doesn't seem possible with the [Admin SDK](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/email-settings/#manage_send-as_alias):

> Any email address which *exists as a user or an alias on the hosted domain*.

Is there any way to start the process users would enter into when manually requesting to be allowed to send mail as that other user / email address?

Migrating the domain to it first is out of the question as apparently, a domain has to be completely shut down before it is allowed to be added to another Google Apps account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to configure a "send as" via API if the original sender belongs to another domain. I cannot see a "click to complete" way for the users. A quick guide for them or some web scraping / Selenium could help you.

Maybe, if it were a domain alias or a subdomain instead of a different Google Apps account, you could.

Have you contacted Google Apps Support regarding this issue?

Comment: It's not possible to setup email aliases via Apps Script either.

Comment: Ugh, unfortunately, this seems to be true. Google support knows no other way either (and their native migrating capabilities are close to non-existent).